# EJB Weblogic JPA java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

I'm trying to make an EJB-JPA project, in my EJB module , the persistence unit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DB">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/db</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.demo.entity.TestDept</class>
        <class>com.demo.entity.TestEmployee</class>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I've tested the datasource on weblogic, it's working. The daos are like this one .

```
@Stateless
public class TestEmployeeDao implements TestEmployeeDaoRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PersistenceUnits.DB_DATA_SOURCE)
    private EntityManager em;
//....


}
```

I inject the dao this way

```
@EJB
TestEmployeeDaoRemote testEmployeeDao;
```

I get this error

```
<Sep 5, 2016 5:06:30 PM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "com.Demo-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT".> 
<Sep 5, 2016 5:06:30 PM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:123)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:239)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.lookUpDataSource(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:308)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.lookUpDataSources(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:298)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.init(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:105)
    at weblogic.persistence.BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.createPersistenceUnitInfo(BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.java:53)
    at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:420)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I can't understand the problem. Any help?

Comment: It seems that you've a JNDI lookup mismatch during the creation of persistence unit. In [WebLogic Web Tutorial • JNDI Datasource Setup](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/WebLogic_Web_Tutorial#JNDI_Datasource_Setup), it said that _"Note: Your <jta-data-source> element in persistence.xml must match the JNDI Name: on the server admin page Home >Summary of JDBC Data Sources - either prefixed with jdbc/ or not."_ Did you check that? Could you show the JNDI Name of the DB datasource?

Comment: That ClassCastException makes me think that you may have WebLogic jars bundled in your application.

Comment: @MincongHuang yes, its the same

Comment: @SteveC
No , I didn't include any.